# What’s is Essentialism

Tags: plato, essence, platonism

Is this statement wrong?:

Essentialism is the belief that (a) the Platonic world of forms exist, that (b) everything in this world is an imperfect embodiment of these forms, and (c) you can specify what something is by specifying a certain set of forms that that thing embodies.

I just read the Wikipedia essentialism page (only thing I’ve ever read about essentialism) and this is what I took away.

Please critique the ideas where wrong. Thank you.

Comment: While Plato's essentialism was the first version historically, already Aristotle proposed an alternative without the Platonic realm, and today there are many others, including [scientific essentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_essentialism). Essentialism only means that some objects have essential properties, those they can not lose without ceasing to be what they are, not any particular theory of the nature of properties, such as the theory of Platonic forms, see [SEP, Essential vs. Accidental Properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental/).

Comment: @Conifold thank you

Comment: Any belief in [natural kinds](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/), where each "kind" has some essential features that differentiate it from other kinds, can be a type of essentialism.

Comment: Suppose Lydia is beautiful. Lydia participates the form of Beauty. But this form is not Lydia's essence. Beauty is an accidental property of Lydia. Beauty is the essence of Lydia's beauty , but not Lydia's. All this to say that the common dictum " platonic forms are essences" is not precise enough, and is somewhat misleading .